# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT error even when using return statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I get this error when I try and send a POST request to the server:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\Users\William\OneDrive - William Harrison\User\Documents\Coding\Social App\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\Users\William\OneDrive - William Harrison\User\Documents\Coding\Social App\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\Users\William\OneDrive - William Harrison\User\Documents\Coding\Social App\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)
    at D:\Users\William\OneDrive - William Harrison\User\Documents\Coding\Social App\src\api\endpoints\account\create.js:35:36
    at D:\Users\William\OneDrive - William Harrison\User\Documents\Coding\Social App\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:5214:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

The router and routes are working fine it's just the endpoint.

It will respond to the client with `{code:"EMAIL_TAKEN"}` which is expected but then it also tries to send the USERNAME_TAKEN thing

I have tried moving parts of the code into separate files and using different status codes.

Code:

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
    const schema = require("../../models/account");

    const username = req.headers.username;
    const email = req.headers.email;

    if(!username) {
        return res.status(400).json({ "code": "NO_USERNAME" });
    }

    if(!email) {
        return res.status(400).json({ "code": "NO_EMAIL" });
    }

    if(username.length > 20) {
        return res.status(400).json({ "code": "USERNAME_TOO_LONG" });
    }

    schema.findOne({ username }, async (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(500);
        }

        if(data) {
            return res.status(400).json({ "code": "USERNAME_TAKEN" });
        }
    })

    schema.findOne({ email }, async (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(500);
        }

        if(data) {
            return res.status(400).json({ "code": "EMAIL_TAKEN" });
        }
    })

    schema.findOne({ username, email }, async (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(500);
        }

        if(!data) {
            data = new schema({
                username,
                email
            })
    
            await data.save();
    
            return res.status(200).json({ "code": "CREATED_ACCOUNT" });
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your code in the question itself.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I have: https://pastebin.com/4KPfnBZV

Comment: In the question itself means not hidden behind a hyperlink (and a cumbersome cookie acceptance dialog).

Answer (score 0):

Using `return` in the `findOne()` callbacks won't stop the other `schema.findOne()` calls from being made. I'd recommend awaiting on Mongoose's promise API instead to keep everything nice and flat

```js
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const schema = require("../../models/account");

  // headers? 
  const username = req.headers.username;
  const email = req.headers.email;

  if (!username) {
    return res.status(400).json({ code: "NO_USERNAME" });
  }

  if (!email) {
    return res.status(400).json({ code: "NO_EMAIL" });
  }

  if (username.length > 20) {
    return res.status(400).json({ code: "USERNAME_TOO_LONG" });
  }

  try {
    if (await schema.exists({ username })) {
      return res.status(409).json({ code: "USERNAME_TAKEN" });
    }
    if (await schema.exists({ email })) {
      return res.status(409).json({ code: "EMAIL_TAKEN" });
    }

    const data = new schema({
      username,
      email,
    });

    await data.save();

    return res.status(201).json({ code: "CREATED_ACCOUNT" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
};
```

---

On my comment about sending your `username` and `email` values via headers... typically you would send them via a POST request in the request body.

For example, client-side...

```js
fetch("/accounts", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify({ username, email }),
})
```

and server-side...

```js
const { username, email } = req.body;
```

You just need to include the appropriate request body middleware, eg

```js
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: I do send the data (new username & email) through the headers of the request, because I just found that easiest.

Comment: @WilliamHarrison I guess it's not very typical, hence the comment. Most would use the request body

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to do that so I just used headers.

Comment: @William I've added an extra note to my answer